# optimize.portfolio not processing 'mean' objective

Tags: equities, programming, portfolio-optimization

I've just started investigating the capabilities of the PortfolioAnalytics package. I've had it working for smaller considerations, around 20 stocks. These return all objectives I have registered (mean and ES). However I have now started to consider larger groups of stocks (~190) and now optimize.portfolio is not reporting the mean. The code I'm using:

```
asxsmlords <- read_csv('indexdetails/20200601-small-ords-cleaned.csv')
remove_codes <- c('SDA','AQG','IFN','VRL','VVR','ISX')
asxsmlordscodes <- asxsmlords %>% filter(!(Code %in% remove_codes)) %>% select(Code)
asxsmlordsindvreturns <- getDailyLogReturns(asxsmlordscodes$Code, '2019-01-01')

tickers <- asxsmlordscodes$Code
returns <- asxsmlordsindvreturns

init_portf <- portfolio.spec(assets=tickers)

mues_portf <- init_portf

mues_portf <- add.constraint(mues_portf, type="full_investment")
mues_portf <- add.constraint(mues_portf, type="long_only")

mues_portf <- add.objective(mues_portf, type="return", name="mean")
mues_portf <- add.objective(mues_portf, type="risk", name="ES")

opt_qu <- optimize.portfolio(R=returns,
                             portfolio = mues_portf,
                             optimize_method = "ROI",
                             trace = T)

print(opt_qu)
```

which outputs:

```
Objective Measure:
     ES 
0.01114
```

which is missing the 'return' mean objective.

`getDailyLogReturns` is just a helper function I've created to retrieve the data and convert to log returns.

The resulting weights are all based on only the lowest risk position when reviewed against the results of `chart.EF.Weights()`.

I also applied to `sum(is.na(asxsmlordsindvreturns))` to determine if somehow NA's were upsetting mean. The result of the expression is 0.

To ensure I wasn't changing anything between the smaller consideration and the larger consideration I only changed the `tickers` and `returns` variables between the two runs.

Can anyone shed any light on why optimize.portfolio() is ignoring the return objective? I realise there is a good chance it is operator error but I've been looking through each line and nothing has jumped out at me.

Regards,

Ashley

Comment: I tried your code with a dataset consisting of more than 250 stocks from SPY. Here, I got a mean objective in the end, so I don't think the increase in asset size is the problem. You have to look at your data, and try to re-run your code it in smaller sets eg. 50 stocks, 75 stocks, 100 stocks, in order to observe when it breaks down. Maybe that'll help?

Comment: Yep, I narrowed it down to single stock that was causing the issue. I scanned the return values and nothing appeared to be out of whack. There were quite a few zero values. Interestingly the mean of the returns was exactly zero, sd around 0.03. Is possible the mean of zero is upsetting the fitting algorithm?

Comment: It might be possible. The best option is simply to disregard this stock. If you cannot do that, you can always try and add some small positive amount to one of the returns for the stock such that the mean is slightly away from zero, and see if that fixes the problem.